# Pass parameter that will return all rows

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on an ASP.NET application that will call a simple Stored Procedure. The SP looks something like this:

```
Select * 
from empTable 
where ID = @ID AND Department = @DeptID 
  and status = @status 
  and role = @role
```

The ASP.NET application will pass a value to the each parameter in the stored procedure. Every parameter can be null or have a value. However, if the user enter nothing (null or empty), it should return everything in that `empTable` as if  `Select * from empTable` with no `Where` clause.

However, due to the orders from the management:

1. I CANNOT change the code in ASP.NET application.
2. I CANNOT use dynamic SQL.
3. I'm only allowed to modify the stored procedure.

Is there any way I can work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the parameter optional by changing the WHERE clause and assign a default value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
    @ID INT = NULL
AS
       Select * from empTable where ID = ISNULL(@ID, ID);
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me the part where ID = ISNULL(@ID, ID); It is to my understanding that ISNULL(x,y) will return value y if x is null. But in this case, we never specify the value for ID, how does it know what value to replace if it is null?

Comment: Because when the parameter is defined in the proc definition, it's defined as having a default value of NULL. If you don't pass one in, it will assume the default value.

Comment: If @ID is NULL then it will replace the value with ID from empTable. So ID = ID, or columnX = columnX, which is Always true, so it returns all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Case statements work...use case to set 1 = 1 when @id = 'all' (or whatever you want the @id to equal for all)

```
 Select * from empTable where
case when @id = 'all' then 1 else id end
 =
case when @id = 'all' then 1 else @id
```

JodyT's answer is better...this works, but not as pretty